# PHP form not finding empty field

Tags: php, forms, email, send

I have been turing this php form upside down but I am not finding why the error message is not displaying and the form will always send an email even if all the field are empty. there is my code:

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" data-placeholder="<?php echo $name; ?>"name="name">
  <input type="text" data-placeholder="<?php echo $email; ?>"name="email">
  <textarea data-placeholder="<?php echo $message; ?>" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-footer" value="ENVOYER" id="btnContact">
  <p class="text desktop"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></p>
</form>

<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $emailErr = "";

    if (!isset($name) || $email=="" || $message=="" ) {
      $emailErr = "All fields are mendatory";
    } else {
      $mailTo = "test@gmail.com";
      mail($mailTo);
      $emailErr = "Email Send";
    }
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Don't use `isset()` to see if a variable is empty. Use `$name == ""` like you did with the others.

Comment: Use !empty instead it will work perfectly

Comment: @sradha But what if their name is `0`?

Comment: @ FrankerZ yes it will not work if we put 0 , I edited my code . Thank you for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message)) 
 {
     $emailErr = "All fields are mendatory";
 }
```

you can use php function empty or `is_null`

Answer (score 0):

[`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will always return true in this case, because the variable has been set (To an empty string). To check to see if a variable is empty, you should use what you did with `$email` and `$message`:

```
if ( $name == "" || $email == "" || $message == "" ) {
```

To demonstrate, you can simply run the following:

```
$a = ""
var_dump(!isset($a)); // false
var_dump($a == ""); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

After Form submit, if field name is exists then `isset()` will return true. But if you check empty value for any field you can use `empty($fieldname)` or `$fieldname == ""` or `$fieldname == NULL`.

**Try This:**

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];
  $message = $_POST['message'];
  $emailErr = "";

  if (empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($message) ) {
    $emailErr = "All fields are mendatory";
  } else {
    $mailTo = "test@gmail.com";
    mail($mailTo);
    $emailErr = "Email Send";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this ,

I check it in my local system its working fine , error and success message is coming as per your requirement

```html
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $emailErr = "";

    if (!isset($name) || $email=="" || $message=="" ) {
      $emailErr = "All fields are mendatory";
    } else {
      $mailTo = "test@gmail.com";
      mail($mailTo);
      $emailErr = "Email Send";
    }
 }
 ?>
 <form name="contactform" method="post" action="">
  <input type="text" data-placeholder="<?php echo $name; ?>"name="name">
  <input type="text" data-placeholder="<?php echo $email; ?>"name="email">
  <textarea data-placeholder="<?php echo $message; ?>" name="message" rows="10"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-footer" value="ENVOYER" id="btnContact">
  <p class="text desktop"><?php echo $emailErr; ?></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked for me as well. The <php> needs to be before the <form>